# How to take JSON object element in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

When I run this:

```
@message_for = Message.message_for(@for, @from)
render :json => @message_for.to_json
```

I get the next array of array:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

And each of these `Object` contains the next:

```
id: null
message: "hnjghj gjgk"
__proto__: Object
```

So, I want to just print `message` from all of them with:

```
<% @message_for.each do |message| %>
    <div class="m_block"><%= message.message %></div>
<% end %>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse a JSON object into Ruby hash first:

```
result_hash = JSON.parse(@message_for.to_json)
result_hash.map{|k,v| v if k == 'message'}.compact
```

Comment: It returns me html page with empty body part =/